# Xamarin Forms IOS errors 90-713 and 90-546

Tags: ios, xamarin

i was building an app with Xamarin forms and it is up and running 3 for 3 years
now after re-innovating the app and update the App-Store it is up and running 2 months ago
this week i added the push notification with Firebase to the app, Android Part works fine IOS did not
i started with error 90-713

[image]
and after 5 days i got the solution from the followig url
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103652/missing-info-plist-value-cfbundleiconname-after-xamarin-update-how-can-i-fix-it
"thanks to dvlprc21"
after that i got a brand new error 90-546

[image]
i tried every solution without luck
my project structure is as following  [vs2019 solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eapO0.png)

also the physical assets folder contain all the icons
and the info.plist file contain th following :

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>23</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>AppIcons</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon-76.png</string>
            <string>Icon-App-76x76@1x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-App-76x76@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-App-60x60@2x.png</string>
            <string>167.png</string>
            <string>152.png</string>
            <string>120.png</string>
            <string>Default</string>
            <string>Default@2x</string>
            <string>Default-568h@2x</string>
            <string>Default-Portrait</string>
            <string>Default-Portrait@2x</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
<key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string>
```

i tried it with / without the following section

```
<key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string>
```

i even created a new project on mac , one using vs2019 for mac , and one with xcode to see then info.plist contains , but without luck

i am using vs2019 for windos 16.10.0 (latest update !!!!)

can any one help please

Comment: What is "90-546"?  Is a compile error, an exception, an error when you submit to the App Store?  There is no useful context here about what you are doing that generates the error.

Comment: Please include both error codes and description in the question; example: "ERROR ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value" and "ERROR ITMS-90546: Missing Asset Catalog"

Comment: I faced same problem.

Comment: I just realize that problem is came up with the visual studio update on windows, but you can do this in Visual studio for Mac without any problem, an issue also opened for this bug,  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/11786

Answer (score 1):

i solved it

just create a new project then copy the assets folder m then copy the same icons with same names and sizes

files are with the following names and sizes

```
{
"images":[
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"20x20",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-20x20@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"20x20",
"scale":"3x",
"filename":"Icon-App-20x20@3x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"29x29",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-29x29@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"29x29",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-29x29@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"29x29",
"scale":"3x",
"filename":"Icon-App-29x29@3x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"40x40",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-40x40@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"40x40",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-40x40@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"40x40",
"scale":"3x",
"filename":"Icon-App-40x40@3x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"57x57",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-57x57@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"57x57",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-57x57@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"60x60",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-60x60@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"60x60",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-60x60@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"60x60",
"scale":"3x",
"filename":"Icon-App-60x60@3x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"iphone",
"size":"76x76",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-76x76@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"20x20",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-20x20@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"20x20",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-20x20@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"29x29",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-29x29@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"29x29",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-29x29@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"40x40",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-40x40@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"40x40",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-40x40@2x.png"
},
{
"size" : "50x50",
"idiom" : "ipad",
"filename" : "Icon-Small-50x50@1x.png",
"scale" : "1x"
},
{
"size" : "50x50",
"idiom" : "ipad",
"filename" : "Icon-Small-50x50@2x.png",
"scale" : "2x"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"72x72",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-72x72@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"72x72",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-72x72@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"76x76",
"scale":"1x",
"filename":"Icon-App-76x76@1x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"76x76",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-76x76@2x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"76x76",
"scale":"3x",
"filename":"Icon-App-76x76@3x.png"
},
{
"idiom":"ipad",
"size":"83.5x83.5",
"scale":"2x",
"filename":"Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png"
},
{
"size" : "1024x1024",
"idiom" : "ios-marketing",
"filename" : "ItunesArtwork@2x.png",
"scale" : "1x"
}
],
"info":{
"version":1,
"author":"makeappicon"
}
}
```